# D-Link router: Assign fixed IP address for given MAC address

Tags: ip, router, mac-address

This is a product specific question.

I have a D-Link DWR-116 router which I bought recently to replace my failed netgear router

On my netgear router I could set up a table that let me define a a MAC address, and what IP address that MAC address would get assigned every time. For example I could always assign my printer the same IP address everytime

I can't find this function on the DWR-116. This screenshot is the closest I can find:

[image: router screenshot 1]

Questions are:

1. Does anyone know if this router supports this?
2. Is it the luck of the draw whether your router supports these kinds of functions?

The `DHCP clients` drop down lets you pick a connected device then when you press Copy To, it copies it's MAC adress into the filtering rules, but you can only assign a `C` or `A` flag which basically means it can connect or not.

Answer (score 1):

In D-Links router, this option can be found here.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. My screen looks different. I have a DWR-116 with firmware version V1.05(AU). What is yours? On the left, the option I have beneath 'QOS Engine' is called 'MAC Address Filter' and it only lets me tag a 'C' or 'A' against a given MAC adress - it doesn't have any options for DHCP

Comment: Just updated to firmware V1.06(EU) - no change unfortunately